# PHP pages working slow from time to time

Tags: apache-2.2, php5

I have VPS with limit of 2GB of ram and 8 CPU cores.

I have 5 sites on that VPS (one of them is just for testing, no visitors exept me). All 5 sites are image galleries, like wallpaper sites.
Last week I noticed problem on one site (main domain, used for name servers, and also with most traffic, visitors). That site has two image galleries, one is old static html gallery made few years ago and another, main, is powered by ZENPhoto CMS.
Also I have that same gallery CMS on another two sites on that same VPS (on one running site and on one just for testing site). On other two sites I have diferent PHP driven gallery.

Problem is that after some time (it vary from 10 minutes to few hours after apache restart), loading of pages on main site becomes very slow, or I get 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable error. So pages becomes unavailable.
But just that part with new CMS gallery, old part of site with static html pages are working fast and just fine. Also other two sites with same CMS gallery and other two with different PHP driven gallery are working fine and fast at the same time.
I thought it must be something with CMS on that main site, because other sites are working nice. Then I tryed to open contact and guest book pages on that main site which are outside of that CMS but also PHP pages, and they do not load too, but that same contact php scipts are working on other sites at the same time.

So, when site starts to hangs, ONLY PHP generated content is not working, like I said other static pages are working. And, ONLY on that one main site I have problems.
Then I need to restart Apache, after restart everything is vorking nice and fast, for some time, than again, just PHP pages on main site are becomming slower. If I do not restart apache that slowness take some time (several minutes, hours, depending ot traffic) and during that time PHP diven content is loading very slow or unavailable on that site. After sime time, on moments everything start to work and is fast again for some time, and again.
In hours with more traffic PHP content is loading slowly or it is unavailable, in hours with less traffic it is sometimes fast and sometimes little bit slower than usually.
And ones again, only on that main site, and only PHP driven pages, static pages are working fast even in most traffic hours also other sites with even same CMS are working fast.

Currently I have about 7000 unique visitors on that site but site worked nice even with 11500 visitors per day. And about 17000 in total visitors on VPS, all sites ( about 3 pages per unique visitor).

**When site start to slow down sometimes in apache status I can see something like this:**

mod_fcgid status:

Total FastCGI processes: 37

Process: php5  (/usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5)Pid Active Idle Accesses State

11300   39   28   7   Working

11274   47   28   7   Working

11296   40   29   3   Working

11283   45   30   3   Working

11304   36   31   1   Working

11282   46   32   3   Working

11292   42   33   1   Working

11289   44   34   1   Working

11305   35   35   0   Working

11273   48   36   2   Working

11280   47   39   1   Working

10125   133  40   12  Exiting(communication error)

11294   41   41   1   Exiting(communication error)

11277   47   42   2   Exiting(communication error)

11291   43   43   1   Exiting(communication error)

10187   108  43   10  Exiting(communication error)

10209   95   44   7   Exiting(communication error)

10171   113  44   5   Exiting(communication error)

11275   47   47   1   Exiting(communication error)

10144   125  48   8   Exiting(communication error)

10086   149  48   20  Exiting(communication error)

10212   94   49   5   Exiting(communication error)

10158   118  49   5   Exiting(communication error)

10169   114  50   4   Exiting(communication error)

10105   141  50   16  Exiting(communication error)

10094   146  50   15  Exiting(communication error)

10115   139  51   17  Exiting(communication error)

10213   93   51   9   Exiting(communication error)

10197   103  51   7   Exiting(communication error)

Process: php5 (/usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5)Pid Active Idle Accesses State

7983   1079   2    149   Ready

7979   1079   11   151   Ready

Process: php5  (/usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5)Pid Active Idle Accesses State

7990   1066   0    57   Ready

8001   1031   64   35   Ready

7999   1032   94   29   Ready

8000   1031   91   36   Ready

8002   1029   34   52   Ready

Process: php5  (/usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5)Pid Active Idle Accesses State

7991   1064   29   115   Ready

When it is working nicly there is no lines with "Exiting(communication error)"

Active and Idle are time active and time since last request, in seconds.

Here are system info.

**Sysem info:**

Total processors: 8

Processor #1
Vendor
GenuineIntel
Name
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5440 @ 2.83GHz
Speed
88.320 MHz
Cache
6144 KB

All other seven are the same.

**System Information**

Linux vps.nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn.nnn 2.6.18-028stab099.3 #1 SMP Wed Mar 7 15:20:22 MSK 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Current Memory Usage
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       8388608     882164    7506444          0          0          0
-/+ buffers/cache:     882164    7506444
Swap:            0          0          0
Total:     8388608     882164    7506444

Current Disk Usage
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vzfs             100G   34G   67G  34% /
none

**System Details:**

Running on: Apache/2.2.22
System info: (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 DAV/2 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 mod_fcgid/2.3.6 
Powered by: PHP/5.3.10

**Current Configuration**

Default PHP Version (.php files)   5

PHP 5 Handler                      fcgi
PHP 4 Handler                      suphp

Apache suEXEC                      on

Apache Ruid2                       off

PHP 4 Handler                      suphp

Apache suEXEC                      on

**Apache Configuration**

The following settings have been saved:

fileetag: All

keepalive: On

keepalivetimeout: 3

maxclients: 150

maxkeepaliverequests: 10

maxrequestsperchild: 10000

maxspareservers: 10

minspareservers: 5

root_options: ExecCGI, FollowSymLinks, Includes, IncludesNOEXEC, Indexes, MultiViews, SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

serverlimit: 256

serversignature: Off

servertokens: Full

sslciphersuite: ALL:!ADH:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:-LOW:-SSLv2:-EXP:!kEDH

startservers: 5

timeout: 30

I hope, I explained my problem nicely.

Any help would be nice.

Comment: start gathering stats [eg install munin + munin node]. can it be it's mysql that is the choke-point? maybe number of parallel connections from zenphoto to sql?]

Comment: First things I would check are the state of the opcode cache (ZOP+ doesn't reclaim memory, it re-initializes when full) and contention on the session files. If that doesn't help, try HPROF

Answer (score 0):

Check your database for errors and make sure the database(s) aren't too large. Also, look at your database logs and Apache error logs when you start seeing a slow down.

Comment: I checked the SQL database using phpMyAdmin tool. Total size of table was about 38 MB and one table, search cache table, used for caching search results had 5 MB of size, and more 18 MB of overhead.
I run optimize table and removed that overhead, also I emptied that table and removed more 5 MB of temporary search cache queries. So now table is about 15MB.
But I am not sure if that was problem (but for sure your note was helpful), one hour ago I needed to restart apache again, and I will monitor site to see how it will be during higher traffic hours.
I will update latter.

Comment: If it's still getting slow, what ukautz mentioned can definitely cause some problems. It sounds like you're hitting some resource limits somewhere, and then it's crashing. What does your php.ini file look like?

Comment: It is still getting slow from time to time, in hours with more visitors is more often, I restarted two more time apache today. What confuses me most is that only php generated pages (CMS, which is Zenphoto on that site, and other simple PHP scripts, like contact and guest book forms which are without SQL data base and outside Zenphoto) getting slow, while other static .html pages are working fine at that site. And like I said only on one site on that VPS, while other sites even some are using same CMS or same PHP contact form are working fine at the same time.

Comment: What about php.ini file, you are interested in all values or in some  particular value(s)? Some values are: memory_limit 96MB, register_globals off, upload_max_filesize 32mb, max_execution_time 30, max_input_time 60, safe_mode off...

Comment: Where I can find or look at that "open file(/sock) limits"?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with VPS, i would look into open file(/sock) limits. Those can lead to strange effects, especially hanging/denied i/o (eg your communication error) whilst having apparently lots of free resources available.

Comment: Where to look for that? Where I can find that "open file(/sock) limits"?

Comment: Where to find or look for "open file(/sock) limits"?
Best regards.

Comment: Depends on which virtualization is used. In OpenVZ you might want to look into `/proc/user_beancounters` for `numfile` (see http://wiki.openvz.org/Proc/user_beancounters and http://wiki.openvz.org/UBC_parameter_units)